# PayPal integration in custom php cart

Tags: php, paypal

i had created a custom cart and i want to add pay pal button in it how should i integrate it with my cart. I got this form code for pay pal but i cant understand that where are we passing the papal's user account id and what is 'cmd' and 'hosted_button_id' for. I am really new to paypal i just want to add a button and send client purchase information to my paypal account.

```
<form action="https://www.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr" method="post">


<input type="hidden" name="cmd" value="_s-xclick">
<input type="hidden" name="hosted_button_id" value="ZEFZFYBY2SZB8">
<input type="image" src="https://www.paypal.com/en_US/i/btn/btn_paynowCC_LG.gif" border="0"        name="submit" alt="PayPal - The safer, easier way to pay online!">
<img alt="" border="0" src="https://www.paypal.com/en_US/i/scr/pixel.gif" width="1" height="1">
</form>
```

Comment: if you created it via the paypal "Create PayPal payment button" page, there is nothing you need to do other than paste the code on your  site.

Answer (score 0):

If you're trying to tie PayPal into your custom cart you should probably look at the [cart upload method](https://developer.paypal.com/webapps/developer/docs/classic/paypal-payments-standard/integration-guide/cart_upload/).

If you're familiar with API's you could look at [Express Checkout](https://developer.paypal.com/webapps/developer/docs/classic/express-checkout/integration-guide/ECGettingStarted/), too.  My [PHP class library](http://www.angelleye.com/download-angell-eye-php-class-library-for-paypal/) would help you integrate Express Checkout pretty easily.